# Can "etc." and "and" be used in the same list of items?

Tags: grammar

Can I use "and" with "etc."?

Example:

- *A lot of people in America are from other countries like UK, Canada, and Brazil, etc.*

Comment: You don't need "etc" at all.  The word "like" already means that the list is not complete.  Just omit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that would be unusual. "And" is normally placed before the last item in a list, but "etc." means "and so forth", implying that the list of items continues. It would be better (more standard) to write:

> A lot of people in America are from other countries, like the UK, Canada, Brazil, etc.

This means:

> A lot of people in America are from other countries, like the UK, Canada, Brazil, and so forth.

Comment: "All authorities agree that etc. is out of place in formal writing. The Chicago Manual of Style says that etc. “should be avoided, though it is usually acceptable in lists and tables, in notes, and within parentheses.” John B. Bremner’s Words on Words says, “Use it informally, if you really must.” Theodore M. Bernstein’s The Careful Writer says the term “has no place in writing that has any literary pretensions.”"

Comment: When I'm writing emails at work, or material for policy and process guidance, I really have to stop myself over-using 'etc'. Once only per email, and in more formal stuff, try to avoid it altogether. I used to believe that 'etc' should only be used in place of the remaining items in a list that could, in principle, be completed, but I'm not so sure about that these days.

Comment: Strictly, we use 'etc' about things and 'et al' about people.